# How to override swagger in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API application to emit file type parameter?

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-codegen, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project with swagger configured. One of the operation endpoints accepts a file as `[FromForm] IFormFile file`

For that parameter swagger generates the following schema:

```
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "file": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "binary"
  }
}
```

I then use [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate typescript client. However, codegen [requires](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/) files to be declared as:

```
   parameters:
     - in: formData
       name: upfile
       type: file
       description: The file to upload.
```

**Question**: how do I configure swagger in my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API  project to emit `file` operation parameter with type `file` instead of type `object`?

Comment: `type: string` + `format: binary` is OpenAPI 3.0 syntax for files; `type: file` is OpenAPI 2.0 syntax. Since your spec is OpenAPI 3.0, make sure you're using Swagger Codegen 3.x (which supports OpenAPI 3.0), not 2.x (which only supports OpenAPI 2.0).

Comment: @Helen, thank you. I was looking at OpenAPI version 2 spec. It looks like my schema and codegen are of the correct version already. Something else must be broken.